# Help Uploading Image iPhone

Tags: objective-c, image, upload

Greetings,

I'm uploading an image to my server using the following code:

http://cocoadev.com/index.pl?HTTPFileUploadSample

However, when I go to upload the image, I keep getting the following exception and I'm not quite sure what it means:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSURL URLWithString:filePath:delegate:doneSelector:errorSelector:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3ea4f8a8'

Here is the bit of code that's causing this exception:

```
[[Uploader alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/driver/ajax/uploadPhoto.1.php"
                                              filePath:@"/Users/someone/foo.jpg"
                                              delegate:self
                                          doneSelector:@selector(onUploadDone:)
                                         errorSelector:@selector(onUploadError:)]];
```

I'm not quite sure what these selectors "onUploadDone:" and "onUploadError:" are all about. Do I need to implement these methods?

Any insight greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `]` behind your URL. You want to call NSURL's method `URLWithString` and pass the result as an argument to `initWithURL:filePath:delegate:doneSelector:errorSelector:`
And yes, you have to implement `onUploadDone` and `onUploadError`.

Comment: Oh right, where do I implement onUploadDone and onUploadError? In Upload.m or in the class that I'm using them?

Comment: According to the code behind your link, the selector is performed on the delegate, see `- (void)uploadSucceeded: (BOOL)success ` in your code. That means you have to implement it in the class you pass as a delegate - which is the class where you are using the uploader.